# Callback a block from within block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think I'm having a brain fog day... But is it possible to pass back a block from within a block?

For example:

```
typedef void(^SomeBlock)(int someValue);
typedef void(^SomeOtherBlock)(int someOtherValue, SomeBlock originalBlock); // how would you pass SomeBlock?


- (void)getSomeValue:(SomeOtherBlock)completionBlock {
  [self someMethod:^(int someValue){
    // How could I call SomeOtherBlock & pass back SomeBlock?
    int someOtherValue = 2;
    // I.e, completionBlock(someOtherValue, SomeBlock);
  }];
}
- (void)someMethod:(SomeBlock)completionBlock {
  completionBlock(1);
}
```

Here's what I got, but it looks really ugly:

```
- (void)getSomeValue:(SomeOtherBlock)completionBlock {
  [self someMethod:^(int someValue) {
    int someOtherValue = 2;
    SomeBlock someBlock = ^(int innerVal) {
      innerVal = someValue;
    };
    completionBlock(someOtherValue, someBlock);
  }];
}
- (void)someMethod:(SomeBlock)completionBlock {
  completionBlock(1);
}
```

In short, the goal is to execute the first block and analyze the callback from that block. Then, pass the first block as a parameter to the second block.

Comment: When you say "pass back" do you mean "return?" A block can certainly return a block (a block can return anything). But you seem to be saying "pass a block to a block." (That's also completely possible, but you seem to already be doing that in your example.) What does "analyze the callback" mean?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. Basically, `getSomeValue` would call `someMethod`, and `someMethod` would implement the completion block for `SomeBlock`. I would want `getSomeValue` to check if the `someValue` int that's returned from `someMethod` is equal to 1 before passing the entire block back to it's original caller. In other words, I'd like to implement the completion block, retain the block, and pass it back in a nested block i.e (completionBlock(someOtherValue, someBlock)). I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Also, as an addition to this, how would I actually get the values from `someBlock` if I called `getSomeValue`? That's where it gets really tricky imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is very straight-forward, but I suspect that it isn't really your question. Nothing in your question suggests async behavior, but you keep saying "completion block." Getting results from non-async blocks is just a matter of returning their result:

```
// SomeBlock takes an int and returns an int
// (In your example you have it return void, but then what is "analyzed?"
typedef int(^SomeBlock)(int someValue);

// SomeOtherBlock takes an int and also a SomeBlock
typedef void(^SomeOtherBlock)(int someOtherValue, SomeBlock originalBlock);


void executeAnalyzeAndContinue(SomeBlock firstBlock, SomeOtherBlock secondBlock, int value) {
    // execute the first block
    int result = firstBlock(value);

    // and analyze the callback (return value?) from that block. 
    if (result == 2) { NSLog(@"%@", @"It was two"); }

    // Then, pass the first block as a parameter to the second block (and also a value?)
    secondBlock(result, firstBlock);
}
```

Is this really what you mean? (I suspect that making this abstract with "some block" and the like is making it much more complex than it really is and that you really mean to ask some related question rather than this one. And I think you mean "execute" when you say "implement.")

Comment: Yeah.... I feel like I overcomplicated things in my mind. The easy way out is to include both of the blocks in the method signature as you did `void executeAnalyzeAndContinue(SomeBlock firstBlock, SomeOtherBlock secondBlock, int value)`. But, the question was pointing to, how would you do it if you were only allowed to return 1 block? I.e, `void executeAnalyzeAndContinue(SomeOtherBlock secondBlock)`. Reason being is that `SomeOtherBlock` already knows about `SomeBlock`, so it's redundant to keep it in the signature. But hey... It works :)

Comment: A block is a black box with one (tuple) input and one output. It isn't something you query or interact with other than to apply an input and receive the output. So it's not fair say things like "it knows about `SomeBlock`." Its type does not indicate that it knows about anything at all. If you want "a thing that knows about `SomeBlock` and also has some code" then you want another type (i.e. a class) that has those things as properties or methods.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thank you for your assistance, Rob!